# Using WooCommerce title in query_posts Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to use:

```
<?php $title_reviews = get_the_title(); $title_reviews = strtolower($title_reviews); query_posts('category_name=$title_reviews&posts_per_page=4'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li class="reviews-posts"><?php the_content(); ?></li>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

But it isnt returning any results - for example I have a category under Reviews category called Product1 (sub category). If I just use product1 in the category_name it works just fine, but I am trying to dynamically set this filter for each product page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=4&category_name=' . $title_reviews);
```

Comment: Please don't use `query_posts()`. Please read [this documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wordpress/4002/querying-posts#t=201611071220004872203) about post query...